# Sharepoint 2010 Remote Blob Storage failure

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powershell, error, remote-blob-storage

I am currently trying to configure remote blob storage in the SharePoint environment. The SQL sever (2008 R2) and the SharePoint servers are running on the windows Server 2008 R2 enterprise edition.

I followed the article from Microsoft to enable the blob storage (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663474(v=office.14).aspx)

once i done the RBS client installation on the client machine, i was able to see from the log that the installation was successful. but when i tried to enable the RBS i am getting the following error as shown on the image below.
[image]

I also checked on the content database and found the "mssqlrbs" tables were not created (but in the log i was able to find that the RBS client installation was successful).

Could someone please help me solve this issue. I need to sort this issue ASAP.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could you please check your SQL-Server Edition? You need a SQL-Server Enterprise license to make use of RBS. The Edition of the underlying OS does not matter for RBS.

Comment: @MHeld The SQL server version is Enterprise Edition (64bit)